# Disable Intellij IDEA code reformatting when closing brace is typed in

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA seems to like to reformat the code block inside braces once the closing brace is entered. For example, if I have a block of code that I now want to wrap in a try/catch block, once I type in the closing brace of the try block, the entire try block automatically gets reformatted. I have searched in settings but was not able to find anything that would turn this off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

File --> Settings --> Editor --> General --> Smart Keys

Then uncheck the option "Reformat block on typing '}'"

Apply --> OK

Answer (score -1):

You must check the option "Enable formatter markers in comments" in

File -> Settings... -> Code Style -> Formatter Control

and then you must put your code between comments: `// @formatter:off` and `// @formatter:on`

[From the documentation about the option "Enable formatter markers in comments":](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-style.html)

> If this check box is selected, the fragments of code
>   between the line comments with the formatting markers will not be
>   reformatted but will preserve the original formatting. After you
>   select the check box, the fields below become available and you can
>   specify the character strings to be treated as formatting markers.
>
> If the check box is cleared, the formatting markers will be ignored and
>   the code between the line comments with markers will be reformatted.

Comment: Thanks. I have this turned on but I do not want to have specify // @formatter:on for every block. The other answers does exactly what I need.