# How to stop reformatting of breaks on braces with intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hey I can't seem to find the option to change or stop the reformat of break placement on Intellij IDEA (community)?

```
// Ideally I'd like it like this:
} break;

// However Intellij prefers:
}
break;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Intellij IDEA code reformatting when closing brace is typed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770511/disable-intellij-idea-code-reformatting-when-closing-brace-is-typed-in)

Comment: There is no such option. I've never seen any projects using this code style, and unfortunately we're unable to add options to support every formatting style that a single developer comes up with.

Answer (score -1):

This [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html) might solve your problem.

> Copying code style settings from other languages For most of the supported languages, you can copy code style settings from other
>   languages or frameworks.
>
> In the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), click Code Style, and
>   then click the language in question. Click the link Set From in the
>   upper-right corner. This link appears for those languages only, where
>   defining settings on the base of the other languages is applicable. In
>   the drop-down list that appears, click the language to copy the code
>   style from.